# `ls: No such file or directory` in piped command but works fine in shell

Tags: macos, zsh

I have this slightly convoluted piped command that looks roughly like this

`grep "tagged" FILENAME | grep -v "tests" | awk '{print substr($1,2); }' | xargs ls`

The gist of it is I'm going through a file which has a list of filenames (absolute paths) and directory names (e.g. `/includes/thing1/thing2/**`), filtering out the ones I want, then I want to expand them all so that I can truly see ALL the filenames I'm responsible for.

However, when I run the command, I'll get a bunch of lines like

`ls: /filename/absolute/path/**: No such file or directory`

but if I run `ls /filename/absolute/path/**` in my shell it works fine. What's going on here? I'm using zsh on a mac. I assume there's some missing filename expansion going on but not sure how to turn it on if it seems to be working when I run the command by itself.

Comment: You're right, there is no expansion for `xargs ls` even with `setopt GLOB` and `setopt GLOB_EXTENDED`. For now, you can force filename expansion with `eval grep "tagged" FILENAME | grep -v "tests" | awk '{print substr($1,2); }' | xargs ls`, but "eval is evil".

Comment: So i suggest you to go for `grep "tagged" FILENAME | grep -v "tests" | awk '{print substr($1,2); }' | while read DIRNAME; do ls ${DIRNAME}; done`. That is just a little more secure than eval here anyway, you should expand each DIRNAME entry and quote them.

Comment: It seems like this is still giving me same error in some cases. `ls: file/absolute/path/**: No such file or directory`

Comment: I removed the asterisks using `tr` and it seems to have worked, although the files don't get printed one per line. Good enough tho.